# How to create an infinite reviews carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone help create infinite reviews carousel. I have been trying for 2 days. Btw, I'm new to web developement, if my code looks hard to see, I'm sorry for that.
Here's the code

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="big-box">
        <div class="heading">
            <h1>Our Reviews</h1>
        </div>
        
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="slide first-slide">
                    <img src="whiteProfile.jpeg">
                    <h3>Sans</h3>

                    <p>“This app allows me to do problem from my smartphone where I want and when I want to. The interface is easy to navigate and I find everything I need quickly. I can’t wait for new feature!”</p>

                </div>

                <div class="slide second-slide">
                    <img src="blackProfile.jpeg">
                    <h3>Adam</h3>

                    <p>“The tool X has really automated some of our company’s processes. We now spend less time doing manual work. It’s making problem very easy for us. Thanks to its scheduling feature, we don’t need staff to work outside of business hours.”</p>

                </div>

                <div class="slide third-slide">
                    <img src="blueProfile.jpeg">
                    <h3>Jane</h3>

                    <p>“Working with Company has been an absolute pleasure. Their team of skilled professionals is not only knowledgeable in their field but also dedicated to providing top-notch service and support. They took the time to understand our unique needs and developed a tailored solution that exceeded our expectations. I cannot recommend Company highly enough for any business seeking innovative software solutions and exceptional customer care.”</p>

                </div>

                <div class="slide fourth-slide">
                    <img src="cyanProfile.jpeg">
                    <h3>John</h3>

                    <p>“App has quickly become one of my favorite apps, thanks to its sleek design and powerful features. The app’s versatility allows me to stay organized, informed, and connected, all from the convenience of my mobile device. I appreciate the attention to detail and dedication to user satisfaction that the developers have put into App. It’s truly a game-changer and a must-have app for anyone looking to improve their overall digital experience.”</p>

                </div>

                <div class="slide fifth-slide">
                    <img src="greenProfile.jpeg">
                    <h3>Spark</h3>

                    <p>“App has quickly become one of my favorite apps, thanks to its sleek design and powerful features. The app’s versatility allows me to stay organized, informed, and connected, all from the convenience of my mobile device. I appreciate the attention to detail and dedication to user satisfaction that the developers have put into App.”</p>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="btn-box">
                <button class="btn btn-left"><ion-icon name="arrow-back-outline"></ion-icon></button>
                <button class="btn btn-right"><ion-icon name="arrow-forward-outline"></ion-icon></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

* {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 15px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.big-box {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.container {
    z-index: 100;
    width: 720px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow:  12px 12px 24px #5a5a5a,
             -12px -12px 24px #ffffff;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 3600px;
    /* left: 50%; */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform .3s ease-in,opacity .25s linear;
}

.slide {
    width: 720px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

h3 {
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

p {
    width: 70%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 25px;
}

.btn-box {
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    bottom: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    width: 80px;
}

.btn {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background-color: white;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding-top: 4px;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: gainsboro;
}
```

javascript

```
var rightButton = document.querySelector('.btn-right');
var leftButton = document.querySelector('.btn-left');


let transform = 0;

let current = 0;


rightButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    transform = transform - 720;
    current++;
    document.querySelector('.content').style.transform = 'translateX(' + transform + 'px)';

    
});

leftButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    transform = transform + 720;
    current--;
    document.querySelector('.content').style.transform = 'translateX(' + transform + 'px)';

    
});
```

I'm trying to create a reviews carousel that when I click to the left or right button, it swipes to the next page. But I'm trying to make the carousel be the loop that when I reach the end of each side left or right, It circles to the first one agian forever. Thank you for your help

Comment: you will get many problems when you want to create your own carousel. care about removing the "hidden" DOM element, make sure keyboard and screen readers can navigate it. and so much more. try some open source alternative like `swiper.js`

Answer (score 0):

So what I did is check if the current is in -2 or 2 which is the first or last one. Then it cycles back to the first one or last one.

```js
var rightButton = document.querySelector('.btn-right');
var leftButton = document.querySelector('.btn-left');


let transform = 0;

let current = 0;


rightButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    transform = transform - 720;
    current++;
    if (current > 2) {
      current = -2;
      transform = 720 * 2;
    }
    document.querySelector('.content').style.transform = 'translateX(' + transform + 'px)';

    
});

leftButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    transform = transform + 720;
    current--;
    if (current < -2) {
      current = 2;
      transform = -720 * 2;
    }
    document.querySelector('.content').style.transform = 'translateX(' + transform + 'px)';

    
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

* {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 15px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.big-box {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.container {
    z-index: 100;
    width: 720px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow:  12px 12px 24px #5a5a5a,
             -12px -12px 24px #ffffff;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 3600px;
    /* left: 50%; */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform .3s ease-in,opacity .25s linear;
}

.slide {
    width: 720px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

h3 {
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

p {
    width: 70%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 25px;
}

.btn-box {
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    bottom: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    width: 80px;
}

.btn {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background-color: white;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding-top: 4px;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: gainsboro;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="big-box">
        <div class="heading">
            <h1>Our Reviews</h1>
        </div>
        
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="slide first-slide">
                    <img src="whiteProfile.jpeg">
                    <h3>Sans</h3>

                    <p>“This app allows me to do problem from my smartphone where I want and when I want to. The interface is easy to navigate and I find everything I need quickly. I can’t wait for new feature!”</p>

                </div>

                <div class="slide second-slide">
                    <img src="blackProfile.jpeg">
                    <h3>Adam</h3>

                    <p>“The tool X has really automated some of our company’s processes. We now spend less time doing manual work. It’s making problem very easy for us. Thanks to its scheduling feature, we don’t need staff to work outside of business hours.”</p>

                </div>

                <div class="slide third-slide">
                    <img src="blueProfile.jpeg">
                    <h3>Jane</h3>

                    <p>“Working with Company has been an absolute pleasure. Their team of skilled professionals is not only knowledgeable in their field but also dedicated to providing top-notch service and support. They took the time to understand our unique needs and developed a tailored solution that exceeded our expectations. I cannot recommend Company highly enough for any business seeking innovative software solutions and exceptional customer care.”</p>

                </div>

                <div class="slide fourth-slide">
                    <img src="cyanProfile.jpeg">
                    <h3>John</h3>

                    <p>“App has quickly become one of my favorite apps, thanks to its sleek design and powerful features. The app’s versatility allows me to stay organized, informed, and connected, all from the convenience of my mobile device. I appreciate the attention to detail and dedication to user satisfaction that the developers have put into App. It’s truly a game-changer and a must-have app for anyone looking to improve their overall digital experience.”</p>

                </div>

                <div class="slide fifth-slide">
                    <img src="greenProfile.jpeg">
                    <h3>Spark</h3>

                    <p>“App has quickly become one of my favorite apps, thanks to its sleek design and powerful features. The app’s versatility allows me to stay organized, informed, and connected, all from the convenience of my mobile device. I appreciate the attention to detail and dedication to user satisfaction that the developers have put into App.”</p>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="btn-box">
                <button class="btn btn-left"><ion-icon name="arrow-back-outline"></ion-icon></button>
                <button class="btn btn-right"><ion-icon name="arrow-forward-outline"></ion-icon></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```